# Network service area - QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, network, analysis, accessibility

I want to check if schools from my hometown are accessible for students who use public transportation, so I need to perform this analysis in order to see if the schools are located in the range of ~400m, but I want to perform this as a network analysis using the roads, not just the buffer.

I have the following files: bus stations (points)- snapped to the lines, bus lines (vector line), and other roads and park alleys which I got from OSM (vector lines).

Is there a way I can perform this in QGIS? I tried various plugins but they are not working.

Comment: Which plugins did you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll show you two options for this (of course there are many more):

**1. Use QGIS 3.x internal tool:**

I suggest to reproject your data into a local metric (UTM) projection. Not sure if you get correct results when you use a non metric crs. (Just tested it in WGS84 and it works, but the results are sometimes different).

Then start the tool `service area from layer`. You can find it in your `processing toolbox` within `networkanalysis`.
Choose your roadnetwork and your schools or busstops. Choose `shortest` and enter your distance in meters. Also take a look at `advanced parameters` to set up your service area more detailed.

[image]

If you want not just the lines when finished you can buffer the result.

**2. Use OSM-Tools plugin and Openrouteservice**

You can also use OSM-Tools plugin: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/OSMtools/ to calculate service areas (and more). It requires a registration on openrouteservice.org and a free API-Key. You can test the service here: https://maps.openrouteservice.org without registration.

[image]